# Sparse array in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, dictionary

I need a vector-like container, with integer indexation, but where some indices are omitted. So what is the common way to represent such sparse array in C++? 
I have an intuition that std::map is mostly used for such purposes. But it is rather slow for container where new items aren't usually added. What can you propose?

**UPD:** Not very "sparse". Maybe about 5%. Items mostly added during initialization step (and not very often after). But access is frequent (obviously I would not start this topic, if it was not crucial).

Comment: Try an unordered map from boost or C++11.

Comment: How sparse is "sparse"? Percentage? If storing of additional values in between is to be expected frequently, some techniques may not be appropriate. Will you need frequent access/iteration in index order?

Comment: Explain how it's slow.

Comment: boost flat map is faster version of map, except insertions are super slow (O (n)) so your usage pattern must be fill map, use map, not: fill map, use, add , use, add , remove, use...

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  The problem is apparently performance requirements, and you're supposing the way to achieve those requirements is to use a sparse array.

Comment: How many arrays, what is the (average) length, and what is the element type? Could be that a regular array isn't too costly, and I wouldn't claim that a map is too slow without benchmarking your typical scenarios.

Comment: I've you're doing linear algebra, then there are a number of C++ libraries that support sparse vectors and matrices. Off the top of my head, there's Eigen and Boost.uBlas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Items mostly added during initialization step (and not very often after). But access is frequent

In this case [boost::container::flat_map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx) can be a good option for you. It is basically just a sorted vector. Advantages (stolen from the website):

- Faster lookup than standard associative containers
- Much faster iteration than standard associative containers
- Less memory consumption for small objects (and for big objects if shrink_to_fit is used)
- Improved cache performance (data is stored in contiguous memory)

A potential drawback:

- Worst case linear-time insertions and linear-time deletions

Even if the worst case happens during insertion or deletion (moving elements of the underlying vector), it is still not that bad thanks to (1) the good use of the cache, (2) relocation of the underlying elements may be vectorized (vector instructions). You would have to try it in your application to see if insertion / deletion is a problem, given your usage pattern.

If `flat_map` is not suitable for you, I would try `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, a map is usually the correct approach.

I would suggest a C++11 `unordered_map` (based on hash tables) to get lightning-fast lookup: it's pretty much the best you can do without a contiguous incrementing key.

Comment: Although the wrong question may have been asked in the first place, I don't see how `unordered_map` will satisfy the supposed need for a *sparse* container.  There's no guarantee that an arbitrary unassigned index has been allocated by the `unordered_map` until it's been indexed.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Why would you need it to be? Just have an `unordered_map` of `size_t` to desired mapped type. What's the problem?

Comment: @John Dibling But that's the whole point of a sparse array: not having anything allocated for index i until you assign a value to array element i.

Comment: @laune:  No, that's the opposite of a sparse array.  A sparse array is like a disk that's only 10% full.  90% of space is still allocated, in the sense that the disk doesn't actually grow, but it's full of uninitialized junk.

Comment: It's not really a problem, just an observation.  A `unordered_map` doesn't meet the supposed requirement of being a sparse array.  But like I said, the wrong question was probably asked in the first place.

Comment: @John Dibling wikipedia, "sparse array": "A naive implementation of an array may allocate space for the entire array, but in the case where there are few non-default values, this implementation is inefficient." A vector (as in math) with N elements always has N elements, but the implementation of a sparse array should not have all that useless storage allocated. I'm not sure what you meant by "sparse container", but having a *container* with lots of unused space is not a wise choice for the implementation of a sparse vector.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like

```
std::vector<boost::optional<your_type>>
```

would be enough for you.

Comment: Probably not a good idea. Possibly the right approach, though. Depends on certain things.

Comment: It should work well if the objects are big - but not if the objects are small and indices are big.

Comment: It depends on a few other things. e.g. Does he need to know quickly whether a particular index is populated?