# std::map in class : trade off between execution speed and memory usage

Tags: c++

My question concerns the trade off between execution speed and memory usage when designing a class that will be instantiated thousands or millions of times and used differently in different contexts.

So I have a class that contains a bunch of numerical properties (stored in int and double). A simple example would be

```
class MyObject
{
  public:
    double property1;
    double property2;
    ...
    double property14
    int property15;
    int property16;
    ...
    int property25;
    MyObject();
    ~MyObject();
};
```

This class is used by different programs that instantiate

```
std::vector<MyObject> SetOfMyObjects;
```

that may contain as much as a few millions of elements. The thing is that depending on the context, some or many properties may remain unused (we do not need to compute them in this given context), implying that the memory for millions of useless int and double is allocated. As I said, the usefulness and uselessness of the properties depend on the context, and I would like to avoid writing a different class for each specific contexts.

So I was thinking about using std::maps to assign memory only for the properties I use. For example

```
class MyObject
{
  public:
    std::map<std::string, double> properties_double;
    std::map<std::string, int> properties_int;
    MyObject();
    ~MyObject();
};
```

such that if "property1" has to be computed, it would stored as

```
MyObject myobject;
myobject.properties_double["property1"] = the_value;
```

Obviously, I would define proper "set" and "get" methods.

I understand that accessing elements in a std::map goes as the logarithm of its size, but since the number of properties is quite small (about 25), I suppose that this should not slow down the execution of the code too much.

Am I overthinking this too much? Do you think using std::map is a good idea? Any suggestion from more seasoned programmers would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `std::map`. You might also remember the vector allocation strategy - it is likely to allocate twice more memory than it currently needs - and use a different container to store your data altogether.

Comment: `std::string`? An `enum` sounds better. You may end up with larger objects and odd access. I think that first you should do some calculations: maybe you will discover that the original class is not that bad.

Comment: @SergeyA Thanks for the tip about the vector allocation strategy. In fact I usually use std::list for MyObject since I generally need to go over all the elements in the list rather than to access a specific element.

Comment: Your structure is called a "sparse array."  Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310680/

Comment: `std::vector` will probably still give you better memory use and speed than `std::list`.

Comment: You may want to consider not having the callers use an std::vector<MyObject> at all.  Replacing 1 million small structures with 1 million maps might be bad.  Instead, consider writing a class "SetOfMyObjects" that looks like an array of MyObject, but just holds a single map.

Comment: The only way that maps really helps is if you have a small number of objects to put in the map and the size of the objects to be put in the map is significantly larger than the overhead bytes used for management of the map nodes. Also, your code needs to spend more time accessing the map than creating/deallocating it. For example, if you store many many thousands of pixels, it is crazy slow to put them in a map. Just use a vector<uint32_t> and the memory size will stay under control.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think this is your best option, for 25 elements, you will not benefit that much from using a map in terms of lookup performance. Also, it depends on what kinds of properties are you going to have, if it is a fixed set of properties as in your example, then string lookup would be a waste of memory and CPU cycles, you could go for an enum  of all properties or just an integer and use a sequential container for the properties each element has. For such a small number of possible properties, lookup time will be lower than a map because of cache friendliness and integer comparisons, and memory usage will be lower too. For such a small set of properties this solution is marginally better.

Then there is the problem that an `int` is usually twice as small as a `double`. And they are different types. So it is not directly possible to store both in a single container, but you could have enough space for a `double` in each element, and either use a `union` or just read/write an `int` from/to the address of the `double` if the property "index" is larger than 14.

So you can have something as simple as:

```
struct Property {
   int type;
   union {
       int d_int;
       double d_double;
   };
};

class MyObject {
    std::vector<Property> properties;
};
```

And for `type` 1 - 14 you read the `d_double` field, for `type` 15 - 25 the `d_int` field.

**BENCHMARKS!!!**

Out of curiosity I did some testing, creating 250k objects, each with 5 int and 5 double properties, using a vector, a map and a hash for the properties, and measured memory usage and time taken to set and get the properties, ran each test 3 times in a row to see impact on caching, calculate checksum for getters to verify consistency, and here are the results:

```
vector | iteration | memory usage MB | time msec | checksum 
setting 0 32 54
setting 1 32 13
setting 2 32 13
getting 0 32 77 3750000
getting 1 32 77 3750000
getting 2 32 77 3750000

map | iteration | memory usage MB | time msec | checksum 
setting 0 132 872
setting 1 132 800
setting 2 132 800
getting 0 132 800 3750000
getting 1 132 799 3750000
getting 2 132 799 3750000

hash | iteration | memory usage MB | time msec | checksum 
setting 0 155 797
setting 1 155 702
setting 2 155 702
getting 0 155 705 3750000
getting 1 155 705 3750000
getting 2 155 706 3750000
```

As expected, the vector solution is by far the fastest and most efficient, although it is most influenced by cold cache, even running cold it is way faster than a map or hash implementation.

On a cold run, the vector implementation is 16.15 times faster than map and 14.75 times faster than hash. On a warm run it is even faster - 61 times faster and 54 times faster respectively.

As for memory usage, the vector solution is far more efficient as well, using over 4 times less memory than the map solution and almost 5 times less than the hash solution.

As I said, it is marginally better.

To clarify, the "cold run" is not only the first run but also the one inserting the actual values in the properties, so it is fairly illustrative of the insert operations overhead. None of the containers used preallocation so they used their default policies of expanding. As for the memory usage, it is possible it doesn't accurately reflect actual memory usage 100% accurately, since I use the entire working set for the executable, and there is usually some preallocation taking place on OS level as well, it will most likely be more conservative as the working set increases. Last but not least, the map and hash solutions are implemented using a string lookup as the OP originally intended, which is why they are so inefficient. Using integers as keys in the map and hash produces far more competitive results:

```
vector | iteration | memory usage MB | time msec | checksum 
setting 0 32 55
setting 1 32 13
setting 2 32 13
getting 0 32 77 3750000
getting 1 32 77 3750000
getting 2 32 77 3750000

map | iteration | memory usage MB | time msec | checksum 
setting 0 47 95
setting 1 47 11
setting 2 47 11
getting 0 47 12 3750000
getting 1 47 12 3750000
getting 2 47 12 3750000

hash | iteration | memory usage MB | time msec | checksum 
setting 0 68 98
setting 1 68 19
setting 2 68 19
getting 0 68 21 3750000
getting 1 68 21 3750000
getting 2 68 21 3750000
```

Memory usage is much lower for hash and map, while still higher than vector, but in terms of performance the tables are turned, while the vector solution sill wins at inserts, at reading and writing the map solution takes the trophy. So there's the trade-off.

As for how much memory is saved compared to having all the properties as object members, by just a rough calculation, it would take about 80 MB of RAM to have 250k such objects in a sequential container. So you save like 50 MB for the vector solution and almost nothing for the hash solution. And it goes without saying - direct member access would be much faster.

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR: it's not worth it.**

From carpenters we get: **measure twice, cut once**. Apply it.

---

Your 25 `int` and `double` will occupy on a x86_64 processor:

- 14 `double`: 112 bytes (14 * 8)
- 11 `int`: 44 bytes (11 * 4)

for a total of 156 bytes.

---

A `std::pair<std::string, double>` will, on most implementation, consume:

- 24 bytes for the string
- 8 bytes for the double

and a *node* in the `std::map<std::string, double>` will add at least 3 pointers (1 parent, 2 children) and a red-black flag for another 24 bytes.

That's at least 56 bytes *per property*.

Even with a 0-overhead allocator, any time you store 3 elements or more in this `map` you use more than 156 bytes...

---

A compressed (type, property) pair will occupy:

- 8 bytes for the property (`double` is the worst case)
- 8 bytes for the type (you can choose a smaller type, but alignment kicks in)

for a total of 16 bytes per pair. Much better than `map`.

Stored in a `vector`, this will mean:

- 24 bytes of overhead for the `vector`
- 16 bytes per property

Even with a 0-overhead allocator, any time you store 9 elements or more in this `vector` you use more than 156 bytes.

---

You know the solution: split that object.

Comment: +1. Was thinking of offering a polymorphic demo of a solution but then read this and thought... 156 bytes? how much will I really save after all the alignment and block management overhead in the allocator?

Answer (score 6):

You're looking up objects by name that you know will be there. So look them up by name.

> I understand that accessing elements in a std::map goes as the logarithm of its size, but since the number of properties is quite small (about 25), I suppose that this should not slow down the execution of the code too much.

You will slow down your program by more than one order of magnitude. Lookup of a map may be O(logN) but it's O(LogN) * C. C will be *huge* compared to direct access of properties (thousands of times slower).

> implying that the memory for millions of useless int and double is allocated

A `std::string` is at least 24 bytes on all the implementations I can think of - assuming you keen the names of properties short (google 'short string optimisation' for details).

Unless 60% of your properties are unpopulated there is no saving using a map keyed by string at all.

Comment: Plus O(f(x)) = O(f(x) + K)

Answer (score 4):

With so many objects and small map object in each you may hit another problem - memory fragmentation. It could be usable to have `std::vector` with `std::pair<key,value>` in it instead and do lookup (I think binary search should be sufficient, but it depends on your situation, it could be cheaper to do linear lookup but not to sort the vector). For property key I would use enum instead of string, unless later is dictated by interface (which you did not show).

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea (not compiled/tested):

```
struct property_type
{
  enum { kind_int, kind_double } k;
  union { int i; double d; };
};

enum prop : unsigned char { height, widht, };

typedef std::map< std::pair< int/*data index*/, prop/*property index*/ >, property_type > map_type;

class data_type
{
  map_type m;

public:

  double& get_double( int i, prop p )
  {
    // invariants...
    return m[ std::pair<int,prop>(i,p) ].d; 
  }

};
```

Comment: That has needless overhead that can be avoided. You can use the property number to identify its type.

Comment: Yes, it has, but the solution depends on actual context. I'm just providing an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Millions of ints and doubles is still only hundreds of megabytes of data. On a modern computer that may not be a huge issue.

The map route looks like it will be a waste of time but there is an alternative you could use that saves memory while retaining decent performance characteristics: store the details in a separate vector and store an index into this vector (or -1 for unassigned) in your main data type. Unfortunately, your description doesn't really indicate how the property usage actually looks but I'm going to guess you can sub-divide into properties that are always, or usually, set together and some that are needed for every node. Let's say you subdivide into four sets: A, B, C and D. The As are needed for every node whereas B, C and D are rarely set but all elements are typically modified together, then modify the struct you're storing like so:

```
struct myData {
  int A1;
  double A2;
  int B_lookup = -1;
  int C_lookup = -1;
  int D_lookup = -1;
};

struct myData_B {
  int B1;
  double B2;
  //etc.
};

// and for C and D
```

and then store 4 vectors in your main class. When a property in the Bs in accessed you add a new `myData_B` to the vector of Bs (actually a deque might be a better choice, retaining fast access but without the same memory fragmentation issues) and set the `B_lookup` value in the original `myData` to the index of the new `myData_B`. And the same for Cs and Ds.

Whether this is worth doing depends on how few of the properties you actually access and how you access them to together but you should be able to modify the idea to your tastes.